# compute_partials call order per iteration

Tags: openmdao

In order to minimize the number of repeated computations per iteration I have been using some extra class variables in the compute method that are also used in compute_partials().

(see below code snippet it will be very clear what I mean.)

The question is;

is there any case compute_partials() is called before compute(). 
Is there any risk of using compute() and compute_partials() similar to the code below (see those two methods)

```
class MomentOfInertiaComp(ExplicitComponent):

    def initialize(self):
        self.options.declare('num_elements', types=int)
        self.options.declare('b')
        self.compcou=0
        self.partcou =0

    def setup(self):
        num_elements = self.options['num_elements']

        self.add_input('h', shape=num_elements)
        self.add_output('I', shape=num_elements)

        rows = np.arange(num_elements)
        cols = np.arange(num_elements)
        self.declare_partials('I', 'h', rows=rows, cols=cols)

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        b = self.options['b']

        # Instead of this line 
        # outputs['I'] = 1./12. * b * inputs['h'] ** 3

        # these 2 lines are used
        self.var=inputs['h'] ** 2
        outputs['I'] = 1./12. * b * inputs['h'] * self.var


        self.compcou += 1

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):
        b = self.options['b']
        self.partcou += 1
        # instead of this 
        # partials['I', 'h'] = 1./4. * b * inputs['h'] ** 2
        # this is used
        partials['I', 'h'] = 1./4. * b * self.var
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openmdao does not guarantee that compute is called before compute_partials. U need to assume that are totally independent.